# Cisco Webex API Exception

Tags: java, xml, cisco, webex

I have successfully consumed several other Webex APIs but the "LstrecordaccessDetailHistory XML Request" doesn't work.

I got this message from the XML response:

> unable to instantiate
>   com.webex.xmlapi.service.binding.history.lstrecordaccessDetailHistory;
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.webex.xmlapi.service.binding.history.lstrecordaccessDetailHistory

Here's my XML request body:

```
String strXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\r\n";
        strXML += "<serv:message xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:serv=\"http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service\">\r\n";
        strXML += "<header>";
        strXML += "<securityContext>";
        strXML += "<password>password</password>";
        strXML += "<siteName>siteName</siteName>";
        strXML += "<email>email</email>";
        strXML += "</securityContext>";
        strXML += "</header>";


        strXML += "<body>";
        strXML += "<bodyContent xsi:type=\"java:com.webex.service.binding.history.lstrecordaccessDetailHistory\">";
        strXML += "<recondID>recondID</recondID>";
        strXML += "<timeZoneID>timeZoneID</timeZoneID>";
        strXML += "<listControl>";
        strXML += "<startFrom>1</startFrom>";
        strXML += "<maximumNum>500</maximumNum>";
        strXML += "<listMethod>OR</listMethod>";
        strXML += "</listControl>";
        strXML += "</bodyContent>";
        strXML += "</body>";
        strXML += "</serv:message>";
```

Here's [the documentation from Cisco](https://developer.cisco.com/media/webex-xml-api/95LstrecordaccessDetailHistory.html).

Has anyone gone through this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you based your request on [is unfortunately out-of-date](https://communities.cisco.com/docs/DOC-49171).  You have to use a different `xsi:type`:

> The only supported `xsi:type` is the full path of
>
> ```
> xsi:type="java:com.webex.service.binding.history.LstmeetingusageHistory"
> ```
>
> or a shortened path of
>
> ```
> xsi:type="history.LstmeetingusageHistory"
> ```
>
> [...] As for the schema - You are correct, it is wrong for the
>   list meeting usage command.  I'll have the engineering team fix it in
>   the next release.

Comment: that documentation is our of date and the <recondID> node is not supported. I changed it to <recordID> and it worked.